# PHP, Apache installed but not working together

Tags: php, apache

I'm new to web development.
I've installed Apache 2.4 and php 5.6.6 on my vista machine.
on command prompt, php -v command shows version info.
by localhost:8080 I can see apache is running
but when I run info.php from localhost/nfo.php the screen remains blank
can anyone help me to detect problem?
Thanks,

Comment: try to use: localhost:8080/info.php

Comment: check your error log

Comment: This is not exactly a programming question, it makes more sense on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thank you very much Giovanni Le Grand, it worked. The setup was right just I was not executing it right. Once again thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

### Running PHP 5 as an Apache Module

To configure Apache to load PHP as a module to parse your PHP scripts, use an ASCII text editor to open the Apache configuration file, `"httpd.conf"`. Apache 2.0.x users can find it in `"C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\conf\"` while Apache 2.2.x users can find it in `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\"`. Basically, it's in the "conf" folder of wherever you installed Apache.

Search for the section of the file that has a series of "LoadModule" statements. Statements prefixed by the hash "#" sign are regarded as having been commented out.

If you are using Apache 2.0.x, add the following line after all the LoadModule statements:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
```

If you are using Apache 2.2.x, add the following line instead:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Note carefully the use of the forward slash character ("/") instead of the traditional Windows backslash ("\"). This is not a typographical error.

Next, search for "AddType" in the file, and add the following line after the last "AddType" statement. Do this no matter which version of Apache you are using. For Apache 2.2.x, you can find the "AddType" lines in the  section. Add the line just before the closing  for that section.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

If you need to support other file types, like ".phtml", simply add them to the list, like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
```

Finally, for those using one of the Apache 2 versions, you will need to indicate the location of your PHP ini file. Add the following line to the end of your httpd.conf file.

```
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

Of course if you used a different directory for your PHP installation, you will need to change "c:/php" to that path. Remember to use the forward slash ("/") here again.

If you are using Apache 1, you will have already placed your php.ini file in either the Windows directory or somewhere in your PATH, so PHP should be able to find it by itself. You can of course do the same if you are using Apache 2, but I find modifying the Apache configuration file a better solution than cluttering your c:\windows directory or your PATH variable.

Reference: http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml

Comment: Thank you very much I checked my httpd.conf as per your guidelines. I was not giving right url for the execution.

Comment: cool. If you think this guide helps you with your issue, please do not forget to mark it as the right answer